# Ethernet to Fiber Converters, reliable? or maybe better solutions

Tags: fiber, gigabit-ethernet

Not sure if this is relevant to ask here ... but I cannot find any information on the net about it.

But here goes:

Today I have a fiber that comes into building B from A(I have no control here. Lets just say it's our ISP). This goes to a switch Cisco 2960G with a CWDM SFP Fiber module. Then from a Ethernet port to a Firewall.

This all works ... no problem.

In the near future another building will be connected with a Single Mode Fiber cable to building B. Lets call this C. ( We have no equipment in building C )

Since SFP CWDM Fiber modules is expensive(Compared to NON-CWDM ... in denmark, it's a factor 12) ... what would the best option be? ( I can see there is non-original CWVM, but these prices here is only compared to original )

Is "Ethernet to Fiber media converters" reliable? I don't see many of them and most of them are from rather unknown vendors?

I'm looking for an affordable solution ... so any vendor/products is most welcome.

Or is an additional switch to convert the RJ45/Ethernet from the switch in building B something that is beign used?

Comment: Define 'expensive'.

Comment: Updated the question. I guess i'm also looking for good advise here.

Answer (score 3):

I had very good experience with Allied Telesis. Have been using them since the late 90s and never had a problem with them. Currently I am using them in a rack mounted case with dual power supply, so you're even protected against power supply failure.

Comment: +1 - I've used quite a number of Allied Telesis 10/100/1000 media converters (including both the long-haul and short-haul gigabit varieties) over the last 15 years and had good success with them. I've used them standalone with their wall warts, but their rack mount chassis is nice, too.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a *media converter*. Black Box, StarTech, and Allied Telesis all make models in the $100-$200 USD range that would suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience a small switch with an SFP port (or several) is often cheaper or no more expensive than a media converter, and more likely to be made by a known/reliable vendor (and thus tends to be be more reliable than a "media convertor.")